# Scroll bars in Streamlit page are too small

Tags: python, streamlit

I have to show a very wide plotly plot through Streamlit.  However, both the horizontal and vertical scroll bars created by Streamlit are tiny/thin and thus very difficult to see and use.
Did some quick google search but didn't see instructions to control the scroll bar appearance on the webpage.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to do this. You can inject your own html/css in your app, so perhaps that could work to reconfigure the scroll bar behavior. Streamlit's [components API](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it using st.markdown ->

```
st.markdown("""
                <html>
                    <head>
                    <style>
                        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                            width: 10px;
                            }

                            /* Track */
                            ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                            background: #f1f1f1;
                            }

                            /* Handle */
                            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                            background: #888;
                            }

                            /* Handle on hover */
                            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
                            background: #555;
                            }
                    </style>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    </body>
                </html>
            """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

They key thing is to make sure this code is added after the page subheader or you may face errors like st.pageconfig is allowed only once.

Let me know if this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I added `height: 10px;` for horizontal scroll bar.